# Does jqGrid mobile create with reqular jqGrid responsive design. or jqGrid mobile separate from jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, html, jqgrid, responsive-design, mobile-website

Does  [jqGrid mobile](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/mobile/) create with reqular [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)  responsive design. or jqGrid mobile separate from jqGrid?

More explanation for question:

I have web big old application that working with jqGrid i need to make this web application comaptible with mobile, Soo if jqGrid mobile create with jqGrid responsive design i can easly use it for that purpose, if jqGrid mobile not, then i need rewrite and add a lot of code.